# Activity is disappearing

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, fragment

I have a very weird bug that i cant solve since it does not produce any errors. In my app, I have an activity which calls different fragments depending on which item is chosen from a navigationdrawer. this is the main activity everything happens around. Here are some snippets of code from my MapsActivity, I suspect the error could have something to do with the Sharedpreferences, I store a JSON array as string in a sharedpreference, could this somehow be causing the error?

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

public void setMapStyle() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mShowCityNames = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.settings_show_cities_key), false);
    mShowCountryNames = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.settings_show_countries_key), true);

    String mapStyle = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.sp_mapstyle_key), "0");
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    try {
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(mapStyle);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    jsonArray =setPreferenceValue(jsonArray, "administrative.country", mShowCountryNames);
    jsonArray =setPreferenceValue(jsonArray, "administrative.locality", mShowCityNames );
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(getString(R.string.sp_mapstyle_key), jsonArray.toString());
    editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.settings_show_cities_key), mShowCityNames);
    editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.settings_show_countries_key), mShowCountryNames);
    editor.apply();
}


private void setupSharedPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if(key.equals(getString(R.string.settings_show_countries_key) )){
        setMapStyle();
    } else if (key.equals(getString(R.string.settings_show_cities_key))){
        setMapStyle();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```

}

When i start a new Intent from either one of the fragments with startactivityforresult, or from another activity calling an intent to the gallery, this main activity simply disappears and after the intents finish my app is "crashed" and all i see is the home screen of the emulator, the app is still in the background though. Anybody have a clue what is causing this? 
Here is an example of one of the Intents launched from my fragment, the other intent in the screenshot is called from another activity:

```
Intent intent =
                 new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                                .setFilter(filter)
                                .build(getActivity());

                getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SEARCH_ACTIVITY);
```

It seems like the activity disappears from backstack but it is still in memory, just not displayed.. and the weirdest thing is furthermore: when the app is freshly installed, this doesnt happen at all until the app gets destroyed. after that, on every app launch this bug happens, but i get no errors in the log. What is happening here? The code is visible on github and here are 2 screenshots of what is happening:

[the activity in the background is visible after a fresh install even after launching a new intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSYf4.png)

[after destroying the app and launching it again, the activity from the background disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OESMd.png)

Comment: It is hard to pinpoint a piece of code where this is happening, since i dont know what is causing this behaviour, but i have copied the code of the main activity which handles the fragments

Comment: I have shortened the code snippets